# Remove text from MultiAutoCompleteTextView by clicking Imagebutton

Tags: android, string, erase, multiautocompletetextview

So, I have a MultiAutoCompleteTextView and a ImageButton.
The MultiAutoCompleteTextView is populated with a string for example: abc, bcd, ecf,

So while pressing the Image Button, the string should be erased as:
abc, bcd,

Again if I do the same, the string should be erased as:
abc,

[Example Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt46k.png)

Thank You.

Comment: read about spannable strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

```
String strings = "abc,bcd,ecf"; // Catch string from MultiAutoCompleteTextView
String[] parts = strings.split(",");
```

So

```
String part1 = parts[0]; // abc
String part2 = parts[1]; // bcd
String part3 = parts[2]; // ecf
```

You could use `ArrayList` to better manipulate strings.